# the prob and sol environments of Springer's svmono - how to pass arguments

Tags: lyx, sv-classes

When using `svmono` the `prob` and `sol` environments require an argument (a label right after `\begin{prob}` giving the `prob:key`, and that `prob:key` is then to be used as an argument for the corresponding `\begin{sol}`).

How can I place the label for the `prob` environment and then pass it to the `sol`environment?

I know I can ERT the label, but that is an ugly solution. Besides, it does not really solve it since I could not figure out how to pass the ERTed label to the `sol` environment. Ideally, a neat solution to both problems, but any help will be greatly appreciated.

A MWE that compiles to give one problem, then in an unnumbered chapter, a solution that automatically relates to that problem by means of the lable `niceProb`:

```
 \documentclass[english]{svmono}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{prob}\label{niceProb}
 some nice problem
 \end{prob}

 \chapter*{Solutions}
 \begin{sol}{niceProb}
 a really nice solution
 \end{sol}
 \end{document}
```

What I would like to know is how to place the label at the `prob` environment from within Lyx (preferably without ERTing it), and how to pass `niceProb` to the `sol` environment.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

To add the label in the `prob`, do as you would otherwise, click the [image] button on the toolbar, or do Insert --> Label, right at the start of the `prob`.

After adding your `sol`, right click its title, choose **Insert  Short title**, and write `niceProb` in this.  If you look in the source code panel this will add `niceProb` where it's supposed to be. It doesn't appear, at least at first glance, that you can use LyX's cross-referencing system to insert the label here, as it will insert `\ref{niceProb}` or similar.

(I believe this whole 'short title' stuff has been improved a lot in LyX 2.1, so it will perhaps become more obvious there.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: brilliant!! thank you very much, it works like a charm. Also, I just found out that I can just place a label immediately after the prob environment (which makes sense I guess) and it does not need to ERTed. Thanks again.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Yes, I just added the labelling part to my answer, I forgot it initially.

Comment: This will indeed be better in 2.1. Instead of the generic "Short Title" in this case it will be "Label of Problem".